# Exposing Flask App within Docker to Internet

Tags: python, docker, flask

I have a Python Flask App running inside a Docker container in the default port 500. This is on a Ubuntu server.

I am able to access the Flask App through local host as follows:

```
URL = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_image"
```

Would like to know how to expose this server to outside world. I would like to use the server IP to expose the service so that others can access it as well.

Can some one guide on how to expose this docket to internet? Thank you

Comment: Before you make Flask accessible to the internet, read the warning that flask shows you when you start the **development** webserver. Then read https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/ .

Comment: I am not doing a production deployment. Just a demo version accessible from anywhere.

Comment: Public accessible is what is meant by production in this case.

Comment: Oh ok...I didn't mean production...just the development version accessible from anywhere...just for quick demos

Comment: Trying to redefine words is not going to solve the problem of the insecure development server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should first put "0.0.0.0" as host for flask. Next you need to expose your docker port.

Flask file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/get_image')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["app.py"]
```

Build the docker image

`docker build -t docker_flask:latest .`

Run the image

`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 docker_flask:latest`

After checking everything is running fine in local, push the image to docker registry using `docker push` command. Then deploy the image on kubernetes or VM

Comment: probably you can use https://github.com/gstaff/flask-ngrok